# Does overriding a method affect a superclass's call?

Tags: object-oriented, language-design, inheritance

I'm trying to understand some of the nuances of inheritance but I can't find an answer to this question. Consider the following:

```
class SuperClass {
    method foo {
        print "in SuperClass.foo"
    }
    method bar {
        print "in SuperClass.bar"
        foo();
    }
}
class SubClass inherits SuperClass {
    method foo {
        print "in SubClass.foo"
    }
}

SubClass a = SubClass.new()
a.bar()
```

Is the output this:

```
in SuperClass.bar
in SuperClass.foo
```

Or this:

```
in SuperClass.bar
in SubClass.foo
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Read wikipage on [virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: The above is written in pseudo-code. I expect different results with different languages. I want to know which one people think is more correct,

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the language you are using (and sometimes on how the methods are declared).

There are essentially two ways for the implementation to perform method calls: static dispatch and dynamic dispatch.

In *static dispatch*, the compiler determines at compile time exactly which method to call, without taking the possibility into account that there might be a sub-class that overrides the method.
With static dispatch, the output would be

> In SuperClass.bar
>   In SuperClass.foo

In *dynamic dispatch*, the compiler *does* take it into account that a sub-class might override the method, so it sets thing up that the runtime environment can call the right method in either the super class or the sub class.
With dynamic dispatch, the output would be

> In SuperClass.bar
>   In SubClass.foo

Which method of dispatch gets used depends on the language you use, how the methods are declared and how you perform the call.
In C++ and C#, the compiler uses static dispatch by default, unless the method was declared as `virtual`.
In Java, the compiler uses dynamic dispatch by default.

Comment: @SJuan76, try it in c++ without the virtual keyword. The type of reference is SuperClass inside SuperClass.bar.

Comment: C# is static by default. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Even when the method call originates in the superclass, it should call the overriding method in the subclass. This behaviour is sometimes called “open recursion”, and this feature is crucial for techniques like the “strategy pattern”. Open recursion is generally considered to be a fundamental concept of object-oriented programming, although it is not without problems.

There are some caveats as some languages add special requirements.

- In some languages, you always have to invoke methods with the dot-notation for this to work. You'd have to say `this.foo()` rather than just `foo()`.
- Some languages require you to explicitly mark methods as overrideable. E.g. C++ would require the `foo` method to be marked `virtual` for this to work as expected. In most languages, methods can be overridden by default.

Comment: But with `this.foo()`, does `this` refer to the class or the object?

Comment: @shawnhcorey Many object-oriented language offer a keyword such as `this` or `self` to access the current instance, or simply pass it as the first parameter to the method. These keywords/variables always refer to the object that the method was called on.

Comment: Can you give an example of a language with the first caveat? I've not run into that before.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Languages such as Perl or Python require explicit syntax for method dispatch. Especially in Perl is it possible for this error to go unnoticed, since there's no such thing as method signatures and methods are just normal functions that are dispatched differently. In `perl -E'package Super { use Moo; sub foo { say "Super::foo" }; sub bar { say "Super::bar"; foo() } }; package Sub { use Moo; extends "Super"; sub foo { say "Sub::foo" } }; Sub->new->bar'`, it should be `shift->foo` rather than `foo()` (here `shift` gives us the 1st param which is the invocant).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In some languages, the superclass foo () would be called by default, but there is a way to declare that you want the subclass version to be called instead (in c++ and c# you use the "virtual" keyword in the declaration of superclass.foo() to achieve this).  In others (e.g. Java and most dynamic languages like ruby, python and so on) the subclass version is always used.

Comment: You say that C# isn't "virtual" by default. But @Bart says that it is ("In Java and C#, the compiler uses dynamic dispatch by default"). Which of you is correct?

Comment: I am. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx for microsoft's explanation of how this works.